# Parsing irregular XML in R

Tags: xml, r

If I have xml loaded in R, for example:

```
library(XML)
top <- newXMLNode("top")
tvp <- newXMLNode("TVP", parent = top)
time <- newXMLNode("time", "2012-01-01", parent = tvp)
value <- newXMLNode("value", "123", parent = tvp)
comment <- newXMLNode("comment",parent = tvp)
qualifer <-newXMLNode("qualifier", attrs = c(y = 'abc'), parent = comment)
commentText <-newXMLNode("info", attrs = c(y = 'something'), parent = comment)
tvp <- newXMLNode("TVP", parent = top)
time <- newXMLNode("time", "2012-01-02", parent = tvp)
value <- newXMLNode("value", "456", parent = tvp)
tvp <- newXMLNode("TVP", parent = top)
time <- newXMLNode("time", "2012-01-03", parent = tvp)
value <- newXMLNode("value", "789", parent = tvp)
comment <- newXMLNode("comment",parent = tvp)
newXMLNode("qualifier", attrs = c(y = 'efg'), parent = comment)
top
```

Resulting XML:

```
<top>
  <TVP>
    <time>2012-01-01</time>
    <value>123</value>
    <comment>
      <qualifier y="abc"/>
      <info y="something"/>
    </comment>
  </TVP>
  <TVP>
    <time>2012-01-02</time>
    <value>456</value>
  </TVP>
  <TVP>
    <time>2012-01-03</time>
    <value>789</value>
    <comment>
      <qualifier y="efg"/>
    </comment>
  </TVP>
</top>
```

How can I get a dataframe that properly (ie. in the right place) includes the qualifier and info attributes?

This almost works, but not exactly:

```
DF <- xmlToDataFrame(top,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The result looks like:

```
        time value comment
1 2012-01-01   123        
2 2012-01-02   456    <NA>
3 2012-01-03   789
```

## How can I get:

What I really need is a way to get the attributes of the child nodes of the comments:

```
        time value qualifer      info
1 2012-01-01   123      abc something
2 2012-01-02   456                   
3 2012-01-03   789      efg
```

Comment: Side question/comment/warning - these lines both crash RStudio:

    `qualifier <- xpathApply(top, "//qualifier/@y")`
    `qualifier <- xpathApply(xmlRoot(top), "//qualifier/@y")`

I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.  For each TVP find all descendent leaves using the `.//*[not(*)]` xpath expression where `.` means start at current point, i.e. at current TVP node, and `//*` means traverse all descendents but `[not(*)]` constrains it to only those having no children.  Then create a list of the values (or attributes if there is no value) one list component per TVP.  In the last line it converts each list component to a matrix and uses plyr's `rbind.fill.matrix` to put the matrices together:

```
xp <- xpathApply(top, "/top/TVP", xpathSApply, ".//*[not(*)]", function(x)
       setNames(ifelse(nzchar(xmlValue(x)), xmlValue(x), xmlAttrs(x)), xmlName(x)))
library(plyr)
do.call(rbind.fill.matrix, lapply(xp, t))
```

By the way, on my Windows GUI system (no RStudio) the code in your comment also crashed.

UPDATE: minor shortening of solution

Comment: I've never seen setNames, but it is immediately going in my repertoire (fantastic!). I don't follow what the: './/*[not(*)]' is doing....but it works.

Comment: Have added some explanation of that xpath expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
require(plyr) ### provides rbind.fill
getDataframe <- function(xml){
 out2 <- xmlSApply(xml,function(x){
 out <- xmlSApply(x, function(y){
  if(length(xmlChildren(y)) > 1){xmlSApply(y,xmlAttrs)
   }else{xmlValue(y)}})
  as.data.frame(t(unlist(out))) ## rbind.fill likes dataframes
  })
  return(do.call(rbind.fill,out2))
}
getDataframe(top)
```

The idea here is that:

- check if the xml component has children; then use xmlAttrs
- If no children use xmlValue
- This gives us a list, but we need a data.frame
- Since some of the values are missing we need rbind.fill from plyr package
- Lastly we need some smart transformations (as.data.frame) to make rbind.fill happy

Comment: Nice. I assume `return(do.call(rbind.fill,out3))` should be `return(do.call(rbind.fill,out2))`? Also, it's not picking up the last qualifier ('efg', which only has one child). My guess is that `if(length(xmlChildren(y)) >1)` should be something like `if(length(xmlChildren(y)) >=1)`... but when I do that, I get an error....I'm still messing with it.

Comment: Yes; it should be out2